# Radius of largest inscribed ball in unit simplex: how to formulate as optimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, optimization, constraints

Let $e=(1,\ldots,1)^T$, the unit simplex be $\triangle = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n: \sum_{i=1}^nx_i=1,x\geq0\},$ with centroid $c = e/n$, and $B_r(c) = \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\|x-c\| \leq r\}$. Then the problem is to find the largest radius $r$ of the inscribed ball $\triangle\cap B_r(c)$.

My question is not about how to solve the problem, but rather how to formulate it as a solvable optimization problem? I've found many answers which provide solutions:
[Radius of inscribed sphere of n-simplex.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2739915/radius-of-inscribed-sphere-of-n-simplex),
[radius of the inscribed sphere of the pyramid in $\mathbb{R^5}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3234202/radius-of-the-inscribed-sphere-of-the-pyramid-in-mathbbr5),
[Constrained Problem, Largest inscribed ball](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761491/constrained-problem-largest-inscribed-ball), but I've yet to find any information on how to actually formulate it as an optimization problem of the form
\begin{align}
\text{minimize}\quad& f(x)\\
\text{subject to}\quad& h_i(x) = 0,i=1,\ldots,m,\\
&g_j(x) \leq 0,j=1,\ldots,l.
\end{align}

On the surface, I think the problem can be stated as
\begin{align}
\text{maximize}\quad& r\\
\text{subject to}\quad& r\leq\|x-c\|,\\
& e^Tx =1,\\
& x\geq 0,
\end{align}
however this is does not seem correct to me since $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$ is a feasible solution and $\|e_1 - e/n\|=\sqrt{(1-1/n)^2+\frac{n-1}{n^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n}} >\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n-1)}}.$ It is obvious that I miss some constraints that include the faces of the simplex, but I'm not sure how to formulate them. Any help in this regard would be appreciated!

Comment: It is easy, but not that easy. You need to use some clever property of the norm. The model is in https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/sdo.html#extremal-ellipsoids for an ellipsoid, for a ball it simplifies a lot, you will work out how.

Comment: This special case (ball and not ellipsoid) is also known as Chebyshev center.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thanks for the link, however I'm already aware of this formulation. I'm also aware that this is a specific case of the Chebyshev ball/center (see third linked question). The issue I have is how to formulate the face constraints that guarantee the ball stays within the boundary of the simplex.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean then. You know the standard LP formulation of the problem. What do you mean by "the face constraints" ? These are the constraints that appear in the LP formulation. There is one per face.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek See Tony Mathew's answer, I think it perfectly illustrates what I try to do, but I see that this answer faces the same issue I have, i.e. how to correctly formulate the constraints that the $n-1$ ball is contained within the simplex. In other words, what are the constraints that the ball is bounded by the $n-2$-dimensional faces of the simplex (in $\mathbb{R}^3$ these would be the edges of the triangle).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the problem correctly, we want to maximize the radius of  the inscribed $n-1$ dimensional ball formed by the intersection of a $n-$ ball of arbitrary size about the $n-$ unit simplex's centroid and the simplex, such that the intersection is a $n-1$ - ball. We can deduce that if every point on the shell of the $n-1$ - ball lies on the intersection, then the entire ball must also, and that the $n-1$ - ball must have the same radius as the $n-$ ball.

So we can formulate as,
\begin{align}
   \max_{R} \quad &R \\
   \text{s.t.} \quad &e^Tx = 1 \, \text{and} \, x\geq 0 \quad \forall\, x = c+Rv \; \text{s.t.}||v||_2 = 1 \\
   &R \geq 0
\end{align}

Simplifying,
\begin{align}
   \max_{R} \quad &R \\
   \text{s.t.} \quad &e^T(c+Rv) = 1 \quad &&\forall\, ||v||_2 = 1 \\
   &c+Rv \geq 0 \quad &&\forall\, ||v||_2 = 1 \\
   &R \geq 0
\end{align}

I don't know how to properly implement the $\forall\,||v||_2 = 1$ part in an optimization formulation.  One idea is to numerically discrete the space of $||v||_2 = 1$, and check the constraint only for the discretization. Another idea is embedded optimization
\begin{align}
   \max_{R} \quad &R \\
   \text{s.t.} \quad &\left[\min_{v : ||v||_2 = 1 } e^T(c+Rv)\right] = 1 \\
      &\left[\max_{v : ||v||_2 = 1 } e^T(c+Rv)\right] = 1 \\
      &\left[\min_{v : ||v||_2 = 1 } c+Rv\right] \geq 0 \\
      &R \geq 0
\end{align}

Comment: I think simply placing $\|v\|=1$ as a constraint is enough. Then the decision variables are $v$ and $R$, nice job! However, I do feel that the problem can be equivalently formulated as a convex problem, which is not the case for your formulation.

Comment: If we just use $||v||=1$, then I feel the optimizer would return the circumradius, as it could choose $x = c + Rv$ as one of the vertices of the simplex (like in the example in your post). $||v||=1$ means that only one point on the inscribed ball's shell needs to be in the simplex, but $\forall \, ||v||=1$ means the entire shell needs to be in the simplex, which I believe is what you want. I agree that the way I wrote won't be easy to make convex, and I unfortunately don't have any ideas there